# Rename and create indicator variables?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in which one of the columns ('subject') has a bit of an odd format. I would like to eliminate all observations where the first digit is greater than one. Additionally, I would like to create indicator variables for the remaining observations, and eliminate the number from the beginning.

So I want this:

```
Subject
1; HMB 2 (HB)
1; HRB 4 (HB-R)
2; HRB 1 (HB-L);  HRB4
1; HRB 2 (HB-L)
```

To become this:

```
HMB 2 (HB)     HRB 4 (HB-R)       HRB 2 (HB-L)
1                0                   0
0                1                   0
0                0                   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate` to get data in different columns, keep observations which are less than equal to 1 and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(Subject, c('col1', 'col2'), 
           sep = ';', extra = 'drop', convert = TRUE) %>%
  filter(col1 <= 1) %>%
  mutate(col1 = 1,
         row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col2, values_from = col1, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-row)

#   ` HMB 2 (HB)` ` HRB 4 (HB-R)` ` HRB 2 (HB-L)`
#          <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
#1             1               0               0
#2             0               1               0
#3             0               0               1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Subject = c("1; HMB 2 (HB)", "1; HRB 4 (HB-R)", 
"2; HRB 1 (HB-L);  HRB4", "1; HRB 2 (HB-L)")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% separate(col = Subject, into = c('count','Subject', 'Subject2'), sep = ';') %>% 
filter(!count >1) %>% select(1,2) %>% type.convert(as.is = T) %>% 
mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = Subject, values_from = count, values_fill = 0) %>% 
select(-ID)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ` HMB 2 (HB)` ` HRB 4 (HB-R)` ` HRB 2 (HB-L)`
          <int>           <int>           <int>
1             1               0               0
2             0               1               0
3             0               0               1
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic `dplyr` approach. You can separate the values into rows and then filter by group. In this way, you can avoid specifying the columns to be created for each `Subject`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), value = 1L) %>% 
  separate_rows(Subject, sep = ";\\s*") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number() > 1L & as.integer(Subject[[1L]]) < 2L) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Subject", values_fill = 0L)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id `HMB 2 (HB)` `HRB 4 (HB-R)` `HRB 2 (HB-L)`
  <int>        <int>          <int>          <int>
1     1            1              0              0
2     2            0              1              0
3     4            0              0              1
```